# Can not read the files present inside folder in Linode

Tags: file, ubuntu, linode

I have an issue.I can not access files from one folder from Linode.I can access the files present inside other folder in the same parent directory.Let me explain it properly.

When i am trying to access like `my-hostname/icons/`, its not coming.But at the same time if i am trying to access like `my-hostname/css/` this its coming.I can not know why this type problem is coming.When i am chceking it inside putty,its coming like below.

[image]

You can check above the icons folder is showing some other color which i can not access.Here i need to access this using the same domain name.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems sticky bit is activated.

Try

`chmod -t icons/`

Comment: I did as per you in putty but still issue is same .

Comment: Could you post the folder permissions?

Comment: All `read,write,execute` check boxes are checked.I checked this in ftp.

Comment: Can you please say how to check this in command lines and how to give the full permission if not present.

Comment: `chmod 777 icons/` to set all permissions to all users

Comment: I did as per you but still same issue.Can not access using host name.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the permissions of the files/folders there? You can do it by running

ls -l

When you are in that folder, and provide us the output.